# iOS: send user direct to health privacy settings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am aware of how to generally open the settings from inside an iOS app, but is there a way to send them to settings > privacy > health? It seems this would be a standard thing to do, but I'm not seeing guidance on this in the docs.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of iOS 9.3 there is no API for opening the Settings app on iOS directly to Settings > Privacy > Health. You should [file an enhancement request](https://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to settings of your app:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

As for the health kit, you prompt for the authorization, right? that's where the users should set everything. I don't know if you actually can show the authorization again to change the settings.

Comment: While this works for most permissions, the Health-related options aren't included here. They can only be set within the Health app and the separate settings page (as mentioned in the original question), but not on an app's settings summary page, which is unfortunate...